# error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Can you Help me in this error

```
    MainActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
                              ^
  symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
```

This Is My File
http://file.lhuk.live/code.txt

I'm a novice and I do not know much

Comment: Have you checked this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId

Comment: That class is deprecated.